# Finding the area of a parallelogram on a 3D coordinate plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, multilinear-algebra

I'm stuck on the following question; I've attempted it but I'm not sure if I've done it right.

Find the area of the parallelogram on the plane (−x + 3y + 3z = 6) defined by 0 ≤ x ≤ 3, 0 ≤ y ≤ 2.

So far, I've tried to solve this by using the points P(0,0), Q(0,2), R(3,0) and S(3,2) to solve for the z-coordinate for each point. After finding the 4 coordinates, I took the dot product of PS and QR as this is how we've learned to calculate the area of a parallelogram. Can anyone tell me if I've done it right, and if not, how I would go about doing this correctly?

Thanks so much!

Comment: the cross-product gives a vector whose magnitude is the area of a parallelogram which takes the vectors as sides. Seems easy enough to find the vectors on the sides given the data you have...

Comment: Dot product? You mean cross product right? Here's a related video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JigcuF4CxI0